# Comparing two array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to have a function compare objects in an array and see if they are the same

```
function alexareturn(alexaword, wordlist) {
  var rhyme = false
  console.log(alexaword + wordlist);
  for (var i = 0; i <= alexaword.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= wordlist.length; j++) {
      if (alexaword[i].indexOf(wordlist[j]) > -1) {
        rhyme = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (rhyme) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My console is returning two proper arrays, however I am getting the error Cannot read indexOf (undefined). If i am getting console to return a proper array right before, how can one of them be undefined?

I would just like to call my function, and have it return true if there is a match of the two arrays, Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is caused by your loops conditions `.. <= ..`, `array[array.length]` is always `undefined`.

Comment: Can you show us how you call the function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer for loop runs from 0 - alexaword.length (inclusive). In the last iteration alexaword[i] would be undefined.

`for (var i = 0; i < alexaword.length; i++)` would fix it.

Comment: Both loops have this problem.